# How to get all historical owners of a single ERC-721 NFT?

Tags: solidity, javascript, erc-721

I understand that I can use the ownerOf(777) function to find the owner of token 777, but how can I find anyone who has *ever* owned token 777 on a particular smart contract?  What is the best way to navigate and trace the entire history of a single ERC-721 NFT?  Thanks!!!

Edit: and I'm talking programmatically querying this using Javascript (vs looking it up on Etherscan).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fetch all emitted `Transfer` events using [`getPastEvents`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=getPastEvents#getpastevents) function. Based on ERC721 interface `Transfer` event is emitted when ownership changes.

```
/// @dev This emits when ownership of any NFT changes by any mechanism.
///  This event emits when NFTs are created (`from` == 0) and destroyed
///  (`to` == 0). Exception: during contract creation, any number of NFTs
///  may be created and assigned without emitting Transfer. At the time of
///  any transfer, the approved address for that NFT (if any) is reset to none.

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet you can use, shown with Node + Ethers:

```js
const logs = await provider.getLogs({
    fromBlock: blockToSearchStart,
    toBlock: blockToSearchEnd,
    address: null,
    topics: [ethers.utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")],
});
```

and then specialize this to the `tokenID` you want. Your use case is exactly why we made this `tokenID` indexed. Literally everybody using NFTs all day are paying a little extra to perform transfers just so you and others can look it up this way.

Here is where that code is excerpted from https://github.com/fulldecent/contract-scanner/blob/main/index.mjs

Also, I have narrated and explained every line of code here if you want to dig deeper, see https://youtu.be/lukshxTYpUw and I have office course ("Community Service Hour") to answer any questions.